# Usage of pipes and dup2 in C

Tags: c, file, pipe, buffer, dup2

I have this code

```
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    dup2(fd[1], 1); close(fd[1]);

    printf("I wanna print this.");

    char * buf = malloc(100);
    read(fd[0], buf, 50);

    fprintf(stderr, ">>>%s<<<\n", buf);

    close(fd[0]);
}
```

Expected output : print `>>>I wanna print this.<<<` on `stderr`

How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to null-terminate the buffer before printing it like that.  To do that reliably, you need to record how many bytes were read.  Note that you would probably need to flush the standard output before using `read()` to ensure that the data is written to the pipe.

Comment: Null-terminating the buffer doesn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the line you printed got buffered, so it didn't actually get sent to the pipe. Either do `fflush(stdout);` somewhere between your `printf` and `read` to flush the buffer, or disable buffering of `stdout` with `setbuf` or `setvbuf` at the very beginning of your program.

A secondary problem is that you're mixing up counted and null-terminated strings, as Jonathan Leffler alluded to in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the desired answer.  It uses the suggestions I made in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936183/usage-of-pipes-and-dup2-in-c/74936635#comment132240442_74936183).

```
/* SO 7493-6183 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(fd[1]);

    printf("I wanna print this.");
    fflush(stdout);

    char *buf = malloc(50);
    int n = read(fd[0], buf, 50);

    fprintf(stderr, ">>>%.*s<<<\n", n, buf);
    close(fd[0]);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>>>I wanna print this.<<<
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
    buf[n] = '\0';
    fprintf(stderr, ">>>%s<<<\n", buf);
```

This null-terminates the string before printing it.  The key parts of the exercise are `fflush(stdout)` and capturing the length from `read()` and using that to limit the output of the `fprintf()` statement.

Comment: Is flush(stdout) mandatory? I want a solution that would work with any I/O functions, for example exec(*print in stdout*) or scanf() instead of read()

Comment: You could use `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()` as mentioned by [Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74936630/15168).  But you have to force the output written to standard output (the pipe) out of the standard I/O buffers and into the pipe before you can read the data from the pipe.  You could use `write()` instead of `printf()`, of course.  Note that your message doesn't end with a newline, so even if standard output is line buffered (it probably is), your message won't be flushed.